# How to clear and rest solid border

Tags: javascript, html

I've added a red border to my input boxes on error generated during form validation

```
 <input id="cardnumber" />
```

The border is set to red in my javascript using:

```
 $(cardnumber).css({ "border":' solid #ff0000'})
```

Now I would like to clear the solid border when the user resolves the error:

I tried:

```
 $(cardnumber).css({"outline":'none'})
 $(cardnumber).css({"outline":'0'})
```

None of of the above works.

Whats the correct css to reset the border?

Answer (score 4):

Set the border to `none`:

```
$(cardnumber).css({"border-color":'black'});
```

But rather than changing CSS explicitly, it's generally better to use classes and put the styles in your CSS file.

Comment: It should also work to set the border to the empty string, which removes the per-element style, reverting to the default it gets from the stylesheet.

Comment: This removes the color but also removes the entire border.

Comment: I thought that's what you were trying to do. I changed the answer to just change the border color.

Answer (score 3):

Try `border: none;`

Outline is not the same as border

Answer (score 0):

Keep the value of the border css before the error in a variable and reapply after:

```
$borderbefore = document.getElementById('cardnumber').style.border;
...
//error
 $(cardnumber).css({ "border":' solid #ff0000'})
...
//correction
document.getElementById('cardnumber').style.border = $borderbefore;
```